# Python all encompassing exception

Tags: python, exception

I am looking at code in python that has a `try: except Exception` block. I have indentified the code that could potentially raise a `ValueError`.

My question: Does it make sense (or is a good practice) to include the `ValueError` in the `except` clause (in addition to the `Exception` which already encompasses `ValueError`)?

```
try:
    func_raises_value_error()
    func_raises_unknown_error()
except (ValueError, Exception) as e:
  pass
```

Comment: Please [edit your post](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/29609691/edit) to [include the code](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) so that we can see what you're talking about.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is absolutely good practice to catch specific errors. There are two general guidelines for use of `try: except:`:

1. Keep the `try` block as short as possible; and
2. Be as specific as possible about which errors you want to handle.

So rather than e.g.

```
try:
    print("Please enter your name")
    name = input(" > ")
    print("Please enter your age")
    age = int(input(" > "))
    print("{} is {} years old".format(name, age))
except Exception:
    print("Something went wrong")
```

you should have:

```
print("Please enter your name")
name = input(" > ")
print("Please enter your age")

try:
    age = int(input(" > "))
except ValueError:
    print("That's not a number")
else:
    print("{} is {} years old".format(name, age))
```

Note that this has allowed a much more specific error message, and allowed any errors that weren't anticipated to pass up to the caller (per [the Zen of Python](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0020/): *"Errors should never pass silently. Unless explicitly silenced."*)

---

In your specific case, there is no point to using `except (ValueError, Exception) as e:`, for two reasons:

1. `Exception` already incorporates `ValueError`; and
2. You don't actually use `e` for anything.

If there is nothing you can (or want to) do about the errors raised by either function, you might as well just use `except Exception:` (which is better than a bare `except:`, at least).

Comment: Notice I didn't actually get rid of the Exception. I realize that its good practice to be specifc as possible with exceptions. My idea here is when the unknown excpetions are actually known, exception can then be removed.

Comment: Thanks for you response , goes without saying!

Comment: @Pradyot why are the exceptions unknown? Doesn't the function documentation tell you what it might raise? If all you want to do is `pass` then it doesn't really matter, but could you not be doing something more useful?

Comment: True, the pass was just a short cut I took. The actual code just logs an error message.

Comment: @Pradyot well if you provide more context, I might be able to offer a more helpful answer! If you just want to log and move on, your current code is probably ok.

Answer (score 1):

A good habit when dealing with multiple exceptions which can occur in a block of code is to process them from the most specific one to the most general one.
As an example, your code could be written as:

```
try:
    func_raises_value_error()
    func_raises_unknown_error()
except ValueError as e:
  print 'Invalid value specified: %s' % e
except Exception as e:
  print 'A totally unexpected exception occurred: %s' % e
```